# ElasticSearch Clusters Setting

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

Does anyone know how to tell Elastic Search to stop node to node communications and then restart it..In my system I would like to tell it to stop until a certain condition then restart the communications ( synchronize data)

Answer (score 0):

By node to node communications, do you mean data synchronization and shard relocations?

If yes, you can do it by setting `cluster.routing.allocation.enable` to `none` using cluster settings API.

If you don't mean data synchronization, you can achieve this by blocking the port 9300 (or which ever port ES is using for internal communication).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that any node leaves the cluster will cause the elasticsearch to rebalance the shards and replica. The overall cluster loading increases when any node is lost since the cluster needs to fulfill the shard and replica settings by copying existing data to rest of nodes. Therefore, if the operation happens often, the considerable extra space will be consumed for additional shards and replicas.

If you fully understand the impact, you can try the shard allocation filtering. For example, exclude the host ip 10.0.0.1 from the cluster:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Other than ip, you can use node name or host name to exclude the node as well.

You can find the full documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-filtering.html